# How should I prepare my fonts to support a Chinese version of my website?

Tags: website-design, fonts, typography

Wondering... Should I first make sure the font I selected for English supports Chinese characters as well, or after selecting any font for English then search for other font for Chinese that matches somehow with the first one?

Would it be the same for mobile apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with Chinese-English prints a lot and usually people use separate fonts for Chinese and English. And like Ryan said, if English uses serif fonts, then Chinese uses serif fonts, same for sans-serif. We don't use Chinese font for English text because Chinese font is double byte and often will display latin characters in a monospace manner (unattractive for English text).

So to answer your question, I think you should pick each font for English and Chinese. Make sure Chinese font is a standard unicode font, or figure out a way to embed the font (web font?). It will also take a little bit of set up too since you'll probably have to create a font class (.ENGtext for example) for the English text.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reality is you can do it either way. I would certainly try to use a font up front that supports English and Chinese, if that failed though I wouldn't lose any sleep over selecting a different font for the Chinese version. Just try to keep the overall feel the same between the two. If you use a simple sans-serif English font then try to find a simple geometric Chinese font for example.

Comment: Great Ryan, that's clear. Would you have a way to use a chinese online font??

Answer (score 0):

I am a Chinese, the Chinese version web design is the most commonly used font "Microsoft YaHei" or "Hiragino Sans GB", because it is cross-platform comparison website general font, considering the user may be PC or MAC and other platforms, font concentration would include the two font, font display effect is better, preference, finally we will choose the “黑体” or  “宋体” song typeface

CSS   font-family: "Hiragino Sans GB","Microsoft YaHei","微软雅黑",tahoma,arial,simsun,"宋体";

－－－
我是中国人，中文版网页设计CSS中，最常用的字体就是微软雅黑和"Hiragino Sans GB" ，因为这是跨平台网站比较通用的字体，考虑到用户可能是PC 或者MAC等其他平台，字体集中一般都会有这两个字体，字体显示效果比较好，优先选择，最后我们才会选择  黑体或宋体

Answer (score -2):

Mac："Hiragino Sans GB"
win/mac :"Microsoft YaHei","微软雅黑"

http://www.lofter.com/

Comment: Mi moretwo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your input. I'm sorry, but I fail to see how this answers the question. The Asker wasn't looking for typface advice, but for a way of selecting one. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: This two line is a little bit short for an good answer. Can you explain what you mean, and what is the meaning of the chinese signs?  Suppose the reader could not read chinese ...

Comment: It would be interesting if you explain a bit more?
Actually now I also need a chinese font to use on the site